# Access Query MAX() Slows Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have the below Access Query and it works fine. However, it takes about 8-10 seconds to finish on a table that is about 700 records right now. The `FROM` is another query that has very little query time. I have narrowed it down to the `MAX()` function, because when I remove that function it runs with very little query time. What can I do to speed this up? I am going to assume as more data comes into the database the longer it will take to query.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, TeamID, MAX(total) AS totalMax 
        FROM attendanceViewAll 
            WHERE TeamID IN(5,9,13) 
            GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, TeamID
```

Here is the Sub Query, basically it selects a bunch of data from a table. This happens in less than a second. The result of this query is everything ordered by date and `agentID`. I then use the above query to find the `MAX(total)` so I can group the agents for a summary. I use the below query for other reports as well.

```
SELECT 
    a1.TeamID,
    a1.FirstName,
    a1.LastName,
    a1.incurredDate, 
    a1.points, 
    a1.OneFallOff, 
    a1.TwoFallOff, 

    (select sum(a2.actualPoints) 
        from attendanceView as a2 where a2.agentID = a1.agentID and a2.incurredDate <= a1.incurredDate) as total, 

a1.comment, a1.linked, a1.FallOffDate
FROM attendanceView as a1;
```

Comment: How do you assemble your `attendanceViewAll` view?

Comment: Without knowing what the subquery does, it is meaningless to suggest optimization strategies.

Comment: I've edited with the other query.

Comment: Also `attendanceView`, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [attendanceViewAll] query is using a correlated subquery to produce a running total (ref: your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21299002/2144390)). Now you are asking for the MAX() of that running total, which is the same thing as the SUM() of the [TwoFallOff] values. That is, for

```
incurredDate  TwoFallOff  total
------------  ----------  -----
  2014-01-10           2      2
  2014-01-11           3      5
  2014-01-12           1      6
```

MAX(total) is the same value as SUM(TwoFallOff). The big difference is that to get each value for [total] you need to run the correlated subquery, whereas to get each value for [TwoFallOff] you don't.

In other words, I suspect that your current query is slow because the MAX() is forcing the correlated subquery in [attendanceViewAll] to be executed many times. You may get faster response if you have your current query refer directly back to [attendanceView] and SUM() the [TwoFallOff] values from there.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a multiple-column index and it should be almost instantaneous.

[Use the interface](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010341594.aspx#BM3) as this link describes if you need help on that.  However, your index should be first on the criteria, secondary on the fields used in group by, so I would have an index on

TeamID, FirstName, LastName

Comment: I already had my table that contained the agent names indexed in that way. I did change the order of the group with no luck, still 8-10 secs.