# MS Access cumulative sum by date?

Tags: ms-access, cumulative-sum

I am trying something like

```
Select myTable.eDate, Sum(myTable.revenue) from MyTable 
GROUP BY MyTable.eDate HAVING (((MyTable.eDate) >= #1/1/2014#))
```

I am trying to have it basically show "Total revenue at January 1st is this, total revenue at January 2nd is this, total revenue at January 3rd is this, etc" over all dates sequentially.

A sort of "rolling cumulative sum" if that makes sense.

Note: There are eDates/revenues before January 1st in MyTable so I am also trying to restrict everything so it doesn't even look at rows before Jan 1st.

I also tried DSum but that didn't work, either.

I also tried

```
select
a1.eDate,
(
select Sum(a2.revenue)
FROM MyTable as a2
where
a2.eDate <= a1.eDate
) as RunningTotal
FROM MyTable as a1
```

Comment: FYI, depending on your requirements, you may be better off not doing this as a SQL query and instead using an Access report to do it for you--reports have running total capabilities whereas with Access SQL you kind of have to fight against it a bit to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im sorry but I dont have enough rep to comment.

What I think you are trying to do is a running total

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(revenue) from myTable a2
where a1.edate >= a2.edate)
as RunningSumField1,
edate from myTable as a1 
group by a1.edate
order by a1.edate
```

try this link:

[MS Access 2010 Running Total in Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299002/ms-access-2010-running-total-in-query)

Comment: I don't have a field called "id" and I am trying to get a cumulative sum by date

Comment: Ive updated my answer again, removing the id column - this should do the trick

Comment: Do I have to say "myTable a2" or "myTable as a2"?

Comment: It indeed works, thank you! I wonder why my original code didn't work. They look pretty much the same except yours has a group/order-by at the end

Comment: Great - happy to help. FYI you are doing a running total, so you need to order the data so that you can tell how to get the sum in date order, the group by clause allows you to sum per day