# Access 2010 Running Sum Field Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, custom-fields

I've been lurking for years following help requests, tips, and suggestions. Now is time for me to ask. I'm trying to create a running sum query field. I return a sum of invoices that are grouped by monthly dates. However, I'd like to have a running tally of the fiscal year (by month) for the resulting table.

Here's my code thus far:

```
SELECT 
    [Regions - Branches].City AS Branch, 
    [Regions - Branches].Region, 
    [Z Market Table].[CMarket], 
    [Z Market Table].[Market Segment], 
    [Time-Table].[Fiscal Year], 

Sum([dbo_a Table - SQL Invoice Level].[Invoiced Sales]) AS [SumOfInvoiced Sales], 
    [Time-Table].Month INTO [Factors - SW Sales]

FROM [Z Market Table] INNER JOIN ([Time-Table] INNER JOIN ([Regions - Branches] INNER JOIN [dbo_a Table - SQL Invoice Level] 
    ON [Regions - Branches].[Branch Number] = [dbo_a Table - SQL Invoice Level].[Sales Office]) 
    ON [Time-Table].[Date] = [dbo_a Table - SQL Invoice Level].[Invoice Date]) 
    ON [Z Market Table].SIC = [dbo_a Table - SQL Invoice Level].Industry

GROUP BY 
    [Regions - Branches].City, [Regions - Branches].Region, 
    [Z Market Table].[Core Market], 
    [Z Market Table].[Market Segment], 
    [Time-Table].[Fiscal Year], 
    [Time-Table].Month

HAVING ((([Regions - Branches].Region)="SW") AND (([Time-Table].[Fiscal Year])=2015) AND (([Time-Table].Month)=9 
    Or ([Time-Table].Month)=8 
    Or ([Time-Table].Month)=7 
    Or ([Time-Table].Month)=6 
    Or ([Time-Table].Month)=5 
    Or ([Time-Table].Month)=4))

ORDER BY [Regions - Branches].City;
```

I've been finding some sources, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299002/ms-access-2010-running-total-in-query):

But, I'm not sure how it would apply when I already calculate sums.

Any thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Regards,
RD

Comment: If you intend to use this query as the basis for a Report then bear in mind that you can [create running totals in the Report itself](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/calculate-a-running-sum-cumulative-total-HP005187388.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Gord. It's actually intended to extract data for inserting into BI analysis software every month and quarter. We're in a process of updating our DB management, and right now my only method to analyze is to conduct queries, tabulate and input into Excel/SAP BI tools.

Comment: I'm exploring the DSUM function within Access now. I'll post once I return the values I truly need beyond white noise.