# Creating a Running total using MS Access SQL 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a running total using Access SQL I have written the following SQL statement but it is not working.  My SQL is not good and I am trying to learn could someone help me with it.  It would also be nice if I could see it in design view after I write it.

```
SELECT
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PayeeID
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PermCashIn
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Year
    ,Sum(tblTest.PermCashIn) AS RunningTotal
FROM
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN
INNER JOIN
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN AS tblTest
ON
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date = tblTest.Date
WHERE
    ((SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date)>=[tblTest]![Date])
GROUP BY
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PayeeID
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PermCashIn
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Year;
```

Comment: "is not working", is a poor description of the problem. Do you get no results, an error, or is the result not what you expect? Please edit your question and add what is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access 2010 Running Total in Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299002/ms-access-2010-running-total-in-query)

Answer (score 1):

I am inclined to do this type of calculation using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT spc.Date, spc.PayeeID, spc.PermCashIn, spc.Year,
       (SELECT SUM(sp2.PerCashIn)
        FROM SubQrySUMPermCashIN as spc2
        WHERE spc2.Date <= sp.Date
       ) as RunningTotal
FROM SubQrySUMPermCashIN as spc;
```

This saves both the `join` and the outer `group by`.  Note that the use of table aliases also makes the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access to test this, but try the code below:

```
SELECT
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PayeeID
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PermCashIn
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Year
    ,Sum(tblTest.PermCashIn) AS RunningTotal
FROM
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN
INNER JOIN
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN AS tblTest
ON
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date >= tblTest.Date
GROUP BY
    SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PayeeID
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.PermCashIn
    ,SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Year;
```

NB: your `WHERE` was contradicting your `JOIN ... ON ...`; amended it so that the `ON` contains the correct defintion and the `WHERE` is not longer required.

Comment: So I am creating an equal and unequal join I changed my join to          ' SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Date >= tblTest.Date AND SubQrySUMPermCashIN.Year = tblTest.Year ' So I can sum by yearas well